# What six-letter word am I

Tags: riddle

> My first and second letters tell you to be quiet
>
> A holiday figure proclaims my second and third
>
> My third and fourth a response to pain
>
> You and I belong in my fourth and fifth
>
> My fifth and last are quite hesitant so to say

What six letter word am I?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Could it be

> shower? 
>
>  "sh..." can be said to someone making to much noise 
>
>  "ho ho ho!" is often said during christmas 
>
>  "ow", a sound that i say too much due to my clumsiness 
>
>  "we": You and I become We when we are together  
>
>  "er": What I would said if i didn't solve that riddle

Answer (score 10):

I would say your are a

> shower

1 and 2

> sh

2 and 3

> ho

3 and 4

> ow

4 and 5

> we

5 and 6

> er

Comment: Nice answer but you were seconds behind. And please use spoilers

Comment: Is “blocked quote” not that?

Comment: Actually, I answer after. just 9 seconds, but 9 seconds after.

Comment: We (at least I) call them spoilers

Comment: A spoiler is >! before the line; I believe block quote is just the character >.  Spoilers hide each line, not just turn them yellow :)

Comment: "> text" is used to bloquote (for citations and such), ">! text" is used for spoilers: the text is only visible on mouseover or after a click